# Find real second order ODE given complex second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem, but I ran into problems in question (iii):

> **Exercise**: Consider the following 2nd order ODE \begin{equation} \ddot{z}-2 i z=0 \quad\quad\quad\quad (1) \end{equation} for complex
> functions $z$. The equation is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and
> $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> (i) Argue that the two-dimensional solution vectorspace is $$ \left\{a
> e^{t+i t}+b e^{-t-i t} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{C}\right\} . 
> $$ (ii)  For
> (1) find the associated complex first order system (that $(z,\dot{z})$ solves) and all of it's maximal solutions.
>
> (iii) Set $x=(\operatorname{Re}(z), \operatorname{Im}(z)): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$, where $(\mathbb{R}, z)$ solves (1).
> Find the real second order equation which $x$ solves and find the
> related real vector space consisting of all maximal solutions.
>
> (iv) Find the 4-dimensional real vector space consisting of all
> maximal solutions to the equation: $$ \dot{y}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) y $$ Hint: Use (iii).

Note that the dot notation represents the derivative wrt. dt.
My issue is I'm not sure I understand what equation they're asking me to find and solve in problem (iii).
So far I just went with this:

If I set $z=a(t)+ ib(t)$, where a,b are real functions of t, then (1) can be rewritten as: $$\ddot{z}=\ddot{a}+i\ddot{b}=2iz=2i(a+ib)=-2b+i2a$$
Thus x becomes: $$x=(a,b)$$ and the second derivative of x is:
$$\ddot{x}=\left(\begin{array}{l}
\ddot{a} \\
\ddot{b}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-2 b \\
2 a
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -2 \\
2 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
a \\
b
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -2 \\
2 & 0
\end{array}\right)x$$

Is this the equation they're asking me to find and then solve?
But that is kind of a weird problem, the solution can just be found by setting a,b equal to respectively the real part and imaginary part of the solution in part (i)?
And what is the point of making the above equation, I haven't exactly made the original equation any simpler.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. It just demonstrates that one can transform a complex ODE (system) into a real system of twice the dimension, and that the dimensions of the first-order systems behave in a similar way.